# How to improve load data time of restangular?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, restangular

I'm developing a web app using angularJS and for the API operations I'm using Restangular.

In my API I already have pagination activated and my data limited to 30 results per page, but when I ask for data it takes too long for give me the response of my request.

How can I improve the time to resolve that data?

Comment: Assuming page is fully loaded and you still get bad times - I'd say this is mostly the connection between you and the backend (distance or quality, or both) or the backend is very busy.

Comment: Well, actually I'm serving my backend in a vagrant VM, so, and when I ask for any resource using any http client, it gives me a response quickly, but with restangular is slow...